# Splunk Indexing Benchmark

Tags: indexing, benchmarking, splunk

I am trying to compare Elasticsearch and Splunk in regard to their indexing performance. Unfortunately, I am new to benchmarking and Splunk, and therefore not sure whether I should use the Splunk GUI with its Splunk Management Console, particurlarly with the Index Detail Instance page or not. Does it make a performance difference when I am using the shell in order to index data or using the GUI to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI and shell will give you the same results

Comment: Hello,

Do you maybe now whether the following command gives me the real indexing time of documents in Splunk or not?

 ./splunk search 'index=bench | eval time=_time | eval itime=_indextime | eval latency=(itime  - time) | stats count, avg(latency) by index'


Thank you very much for your answer.

Best regards

Comment: I'm not sure if those commands would help, but what I would do is get two very important apps that will help you measure Splunk performance. One app is called SOS (Splunk on Splunk) and the other app is Deployment monitor. That should definitely get you, what you are looking for.